# Python syntax questions

Tags: python

For the following code, what do the plus signs on either side of `addr` in the `mysock.send` line mean? And what is the purpose of the semicolon after the final print statement?

```
import socket

try:

    addr = raw_input('Enter URL: ')

    site = addr.split('/')
    site = site[2]


    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect((site, 80))
    mysock.send('GET '+addr+' HTTP/1.0\n\n')

    while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
    print data;


    mysock.close()

except:
    print 'Error, enter a valid URL'
```

Comment: The `+`'s are string concatenation. The semicolon is an optional statement separator and superfluous in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't that be _on either side of "addr"_? You could test with `addr = 'foo';print repr('GET '+addr+' HTTP/1.0\n\n')`

Answer (score 2):

Strings can be directly concatenated with the `+` operator in python, and that is what is going on in this instance.

As for the semicolon, it does nothing in that context as far as I'm aware. My guess is that there used to be another statement after the print statement but the person who wrote this code removed it.